# Is Domain Order included in Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN for Azure Web apps?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, msdn

I have a *Visual Studio Enterprise with MSDN* subscription with a monthly $150 of Azure credits. Can I use it to purchase custom domains for my web apps? Because I don't want the default myapp.azurewebsites.net. 
When I try to purchase one, Azure gives me an error about contact information validation but I know that I used the correct email and all other info associated with my Visual Studio Subscription. 
[Validating Domain Order error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d21z.png)

Comment: same error for me, might be broken

Comment: I solved the issue after communicating with Azure's support. I answered my own post, check it out. Hope it solves your case as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a support ticket for this issue on Azure. 
They said that the issue was because of the update from the domain provider thus domain order being blocked. And **until the fix goes live**, I need to manually unblock myself by registering my subscription manually to **Microsoft.DomainRegistration** using Windows PowerShell.

To do so, run the following commands in PowerShell:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount

Get-AzureRmSubscription

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId <SubId from step2>

Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace "Microsoft.DomainRegistration"
```

Also, here's a screenshot of how I did mine. I was able to purchase a domain back in the Azure portal after running the commands. Hope this helps others encountering this problem at the moment.

[Manual Registration using PowerShell Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzgDH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is supported.  In order to buy custom domain you will need a pay as you go subscription with an actual credit card associated with it.  The way to think about it is that Azure has partnered with domain name providers and once you buy a domain microsoft pays these providers.  These msdn credit applies to products that are within microsoft's control.